# Vendor Management modules

Tags: module, extensions, multi-vendor

Are there any good modules that facilitate vendor management?

looking for the ability to:

1. Allow vendors to submit new pricing, description information, key attribute information, etc..
2. Admin needs to approve information and "**stage**" to go live

Comment: You may use http://marketplace.webkul.com/ magento marketplace modules to reach those features and functionality

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Unirgy Dropship module suite - http://www.unirgy.com/products/udropship/. It has a lot of feature for working with vendors, including defining them & granting access to an interface where they can change info about their products.